# Automatically check list monthly

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have a list with dates. If the dates are 3 months old, I need an email alert to users. This list needs to be automatically checked daily.

Is this possible out of the box with SharePoint 2010? Or am I looking at an out of box solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible with OOTB SharePoint 2010.  You can use SharePoint Designer to accomplish this.  Create a workflow that triggers when an item is created.  Have it do the following actions:

1. Add *3 Months* to *My Date* (Output to *Variable: My Expiration Date*) - "Add Time to Date" action
2. Pause until *My Expiration Date* - "Pause until Date" action
3. Email *MyUsers* - "Send an Email" action

This gets broken if *My Date* is updated because it will be using a invalid version of the *Expiration Date*.  It gets trickier if you want to handle updates to the *My Date* field.  That requires caching the value of *My Date* when the workflow starts and then running the following in parallel:

1. The Pause and Send actions from my example above
2. An action that waits for a change in *My Date* and kills the workflow if it is updated.

Basically what this does is to kill any previous workflow that was using an old version of *My Date* so that only the most recent one will send an email.

Comment: How does "list needs to be automatically checked daily" accomplished?
Maybe some timber job or shceduled powershell script can help.

Comment: @Shawn You don't need it to be checked daily/monthly/etc. if you use a workflow.  You set the expiration date based on main date when the item is entered and you can automatically have it trigger something on that expiration date.  You can also have it update the expiration date if the main date changes.  There is no need for a timer job or scheduled PowerShell that checks the list daily.

Comment: en, "Pause for Duration", it's a good approach for the one off event, for this case it's a good solution.
But things can get complex when you want to trigger daily, weekly etc.

Comment: @Shawn I agree with you about events that have to trigger daily, weekly, etc. but as you said he should not need a daily/monthly trigger in this case.